# How to find path to shared library when using python ctypes with distutils

Tags: python, ctypes, distutils

I am working on a python package that is basically a python wrapper to a c-backend. The c-backend is called form python via ctypes.

It works fine if I give ctypes the absolute path to the library to load it. But I don't know how to find the absolute path to the library if the library is compiled via distutils' setup.py? (The library is built successfully by the install script.)

Here is the important snippet of `setup.py`:

```
libreboundmodule = Extension('librebound',
                sources = [ 'librebound/librebound.c' ],
                                )

setup(name='rebound',
    ...
    ext_modules = [libreboundmodule])
```

Here is the part of the rebound module `__init__.py`. How can I let ctypes know the path to my library?

```
import ctypes
PATH = ???
librebound = ctypes.CDLL(PATH+"librebound.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

**EDIT:**

Is it ok to do the following?

```
import ctypes
PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
librebound = ctypes.CDLL(PATH+"/../librebound.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by ok... I have done nearly exactly what you have several times with good success. I would use os.path.join not string concat however.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it seems to work, but it looks a bit like a hack. I was wondering if there is a better way.